# How to select between two nested columns depending on the value of a third column with spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm writing a spark app that reads in parquet data that effectively contains three columns: A, B, and C

B and C are nested structs with the same underlying schema. Something like this:

| A | B.x | B.y | C.x | C.y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 4 | 4 |

I'd like to convert this initial dataframe into something more compressed:

| A | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 3 |
| C | 4 | 4 |

Interested in what the most efficient way to tackle this join is as I'm working with a rather large dataset. The value of column A doesn't actually line up with the field name of columns B and C, but for all intents and purposes, if A is one value, I choose struct B. If A is another, I choose struct C.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df2 = df.withColumn("X", when(col("A") === "B",col("B.x")).otherwise(col("C.x"))
```